# How to switch to the pop up using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get admin name from a public facebook page. When I click 3 other members on the page there is a pop up with all the admin name. Now the html changes here and a new div appears in the inspect. How to handle that. I cannot get the new html by using driver.page_source.

Adding Images for more help.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code. For the meantime try using `driver.switch_to.active_element`.

Comment: element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('other members')
driver.execute_script("arguments[1].click();", element) 

For now, I am using this to click " 3 other members" on the page. BUt if I want to get its source I am unable to do it.

Comment: element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('other members')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)  

driver.switch_to.active_element

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

Comment: 1/ I think that if you copy Xpath, it should work ( its on the website, so this "pop up" should not be a problem to hndle using basic `find_element_by....`  2/ this is what people refer to a pop up: <https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html>